# Android marker infowindow shows same info from array

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, google-maps-markers

Im receiving the strings from my firebase in an array. In the Toast message everything works fine. But i want to display the infos into the markers. The problem is, that i only receive the last informations from my array into the marker. So all markers have the same informations. Does someone know how i can handle this the right way i already searched for some resolution but im stuck on.

```java
final DatabaseReference getlats = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Events");
getlats.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    final Map<String, String> value = (Map<String, String>)dataSnapshot.getValue();
    String getslat = value.get("latitude");
    String getslong = value.get("longitude");

    final String Img = value.get("EventImg");
    final String Titel = value.get("Title");
    final String Beschreibung = value.get("Desc");
    final String Datum = value.get("Datum");
    final String Uhrzeit = value.get("Uhrzeit");

    double getlat = Double.parseDouble(getslat);
    double getlong = Double.parseDouble(getslong);

    mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
      @Override
      public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.marker_layout, null);
        ImageView EventImg = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.eventimg);
        TextView EventTitel = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.eventtitel);
        TextView EventDesc = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.eventdescr);
        TextView EventDatum = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.eventdatum);
        TextView EventUhrzeit = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.eventuhrzeit);
        EventTitel.setText(Titel);
        EventDesc.setText(Beschreibung);
        EventDatum.setText(Datum);
        EventUhrzeit.setText(Uhrzeit);
        Picasso.with(KarteFire.this).load(Img).resize(54, 54).into(EventImg);
        return v;
      }
      @Override
      public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        return null;
      }
    });
    EventMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(getlat, getlong)));
  }
  @Override
  public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
  }
  @Override
  public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
  }
  @Override
  public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
  }
  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make following kind of changes in our code,

```
final DatabaseReference getlats = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Events");
getlats.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    final Map<String, String> value = (Map<String, String>)dataSnapshot.getValue();
String getslat = value.get("latitude");
String getslong = value.get("longitude");


double getlat = Double.parseDouble(getslat);
double getlong = Double.parseDouble(getslong);

mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
  @Override
  public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
final Map<String, String> value = (Map<String, String>)marker.getTag();
final String Img = value.get("EventImg");
final String Titel = value.get("Title");
final String Beschreibung = value.get("Desc");
final String Datum = value.get("Datum");
final String Uhrzeit = value.get("Uhrzeit");

    View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.marker_layout, null);
    ImageView EventImg = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.eventimg);
    TextView EventTitel = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.eventtitel);
    TextView EventDesc = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.eventdescr);
    TextView EventDatum = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.eventdatum);
    TextView EventUhrzeit = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.eventuhrzeit);
    EventTitel.setText(Titel);
    EventDesc.setText(Beschreibung);
    EventDatum.setText(Datum);
    EventUhrzeit.setText(Uhrzeit);
    Picasso.with(KarteFire.this).load(Img).resize(54, 54).into(EventImg);
    return v;
  }
  @Override
  public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
    return null;
  }
});
EventMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(getlat, getlong)));
EventMarker.setTag(value);
  }
  @Override
  public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
  }
  @Override
  public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
  }
  @Override
  public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
  }
  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
  }
});
```

Comment: The line where the marker is set on the map has an error. I delete the code setTag(value). But it crashed when i click on the marker

Comment: If I set the String Titel in the Markeroptions .setTitle(Titel) it works but if i want to set it with an xml trough onInfoWindow method it doesnt work

Comment: What is the error when you use setTag(value), perhaps i have edited the answer. Please have a look.

Comment: Holy moly! You are a god! U saved me so much time! Thank you so much. Have a nice day.